Problem in A Course in Approximation Theory by Cheney and Light
In chapter 2 of "A Course in Approximation Theory" by Cheney and Light, problem 11 states:

How large can the coefficients be in a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$, if $p$ satisfies the inequality $|p(x)| \leq A$ for all $x$ in an interval $[a,b]$?

It is unclear what the authors mean here by "large". Presumably the authors have some norm in mind, and I was hoping messing with the problem would make it clear what norm was intended. However, I haven't made any progress on the problem. I haven't been able to establish any tight bounds, and I was hoping for a hint. Are there any theorems I should be thinking about or perspectives that I'm missing?
